# input an integer, output a rectangular which has side a and b, difference should be the smallest

Tags: java, algorithm

Could someone have an idea or code implementation of this problem? Thanks a lot!
It is not homework.

Given an integer, write a function foo(int area), this function should return a rectangular and this rectangular has the smallest difference in two sides a and b, and also a*b must be greater than area and less than or equal to (area + 2).

Comment: Is this [tag:homework]? If so, it is advantageous to tag it as such.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) I mean *besides* asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you.

Comment: Assuming it's homework (as it's very obvious), why don't you write some code, run it and paste any errors you get or explain where you're stuck? Asking for a sample (working) code on a Q&A site is just lame.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if you don't have big area (if type "int" then yes), and solution with complexity O(sqrt(n)) is enough for you. Then you can use silly solution.

```
#include "math.h"

void foo(int area)
{
    long a = (long)sqrt(area + 2);
    while ((area + 1)  % a != 0 && (area + 2) % a != 0) a--;
    long total_area = ((area + 1) % a == 0) ? (area + 1) : (area + 2);
    long b = total_area / a;
    printf("%ld = %ld X %ld", total_area, a, b);
}
```

Complexity for this task is O(N^(1/2)). This is enough even for long type. If you are going to find solution for long long. Then you need to use more complex algo:

1. Use fast factorization method to get array of all prime divisors.
2. Use dynamic programming to solve standart task. Concat array for two parts, so total product of all parts should be as close as possible.